# How does htop measure ram usage? And why do thin inits use 4Bytes of residential memory

Tags: linux, busybox, openrc

I have seen PID1(openRC) get reported as 4Bytes Residential memory usage in Alpine Linux.

Right now I am running busybox init on the below machine.
How do some of those processes use 4Bytes of memory?

[image: Using 4 bytes of memory!]

```
 "Measured in pages"
~ # cat /proc/111/statm
271  125      118    187  0   40   0
size resident shared text lib data dt
```

Comment: The RES, SHR and VIRT values are not bytes: most tools show 1KB units, so those processes have 4KB resident memory (which is the page size in most kernels). Those are probably just parents set up by systemd, and their only function would be to restart their child services that exit with an error status. BusyBox would most likely have a similar relationship to the commands that it wraps.

Comment: The 125 `resident` pages of process 111 nicely match htop's RES figure of 500. Same for the `size` of 271 pages (VIRT) and the 118 `shared` paged (SHR).

Comment: @berndbausch That's correct I haven't noticed that I have examined the wrong process when checking statm;
But upon examination, yes indeed it did made me realize that yes indeed the units are actually given in ``KiloBytes`` as @Paul_Pedant have noted, and 4KiloBytes for a program as simple as ``runsv``, yeah it sounds very reasonable.